# Extending a class from the class which is extended from mysqli

Tags: php, oop, class, mysqli

I am not sure if this is possible as I am not very good in OOP programming yet.

I have this db class extended from mysqli,

```
class database extends mysqli
{
    # overwrite parent __construct
    public function __construct($hostname = null,$username = null,$password = null,$database = null,$port = null, $socket = null)
    {
        $hostname = $hostname !== null ? $hostname : ini_get("mysqli.default_host");
        $username = $username !== null ? $username : ini_get("mysqli.default_user");
        $password = $password !== null ? $password : ini_get("mysqli.default_pw");
        $database = $database !== null ? $database : "";
        $port     = $port     !== null ? $port     : ini_get("mysqli.default_port");
        $socket   = $socket   !== null ? $socket   : ini_get("mysqli.default_socket");

        parent::__construct($hostname,$username,$password,$database,$port,$socket);

        # check if connect errno is set
        if (mysqli_connect_errno()) 
        {
            throw new RuntimeException('Cannot access database: ' . mysqli_connect_error());
        }

    }


    # fetches all result rows as an associative array, a numeric array, or both
    # mysqli_fetch_all (PHP 5 >= 5.3.0)
    public function fetch_all($query) 
    {
        $result = parent::query($query);
        if($result) 
        {
            # check if mysqli_fetch_all function exist or not
            if(function_exists('mysqli_fetch_all')) 
            {
                # NOTE: this below always gets error on certain live server
                # Fatal error: Call to undefined method mysqli_result::fetch_all() in /.../class_database.php on line 28
                return $result->fetch_all(MYSQLI_ASSOC);
            }

            # fall back to use while to loop through the result using fetch_assoc
            else
            {
                while($row = $result->fetch_assoc())
                {
                    $return_this[] = $row;
                }

                if (isset($return_this))
                {
                    return $return_this;
                }
                else
                {
                    return false;
                }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            return self::get_error();
        }
    }

    # fetch a result row as an associative array
    public function fetch_assoc($query)
    {
        $result = parent::query($query);
        if($result) 
        {
            return $result->fetch_assoc();
        } 
        else
        {
            # call the get_error function
            return self::get_error();
            # or:
            # return $this->get_error();
        }
    }

    public function query($query)
{
    $result = $this->query($query);
    if($result) 
    {
        return $result;
    }
    else
    {
        return $this->get_error();
    }

}

    ...

    # display error
    public function get_error() 
    {
        if($this->errno || $this->error)
        {
            return sprintf("Error (%d): %s",$this->errno,$this->error);
        }
    }

    public function __destruct()
    {
       parent::close();
        //echo "Destructor Called";
    }
}
```

and I have this procedural style of code which I want to turn it into a class that extended from the database class above,

```
if(isset($_REQUEST['search'])) $search = $_REQUEST['search'];

$sql = "
SELECT *

FROM root_pages

WHERE root_pages.pg_cat_id = '2'
AND root_pages.parent_id != root_pages.pg_id
AND root_pages.pg_hide != '1'
AND root_pages.pg_url != 'cms'
AND root_pages.pg_content_1 LIKE '%".$search."%'
OR root_pages.pg_content_2 LIKE '%".$search."%'

AND root_pages.pg_content_1 NOT LIKE '%http://%'
AND root_pages.pg_content_2 NOT LIKE '%http://%'

ORDER BY root_pages.pg_created DESC
";

$items = $connection->fetch_all($sql);
$total_item = $connection->num_rows($sql);
```

so I think, by theory I can extend this code into a class like this,

```
class search extends database
{

public $search = null;

public function __construct($keyword)
{
   $this->search = $keyword;    
}


public function get_result()
{
$sql = "
SELECT*

FROM root_pages

WHERE root_pages.pg_cat_id = '2'
AND root_pages.parent_id != root_pages.pg_id
AND root_pages.pg_hide != '1'
AND root_pages.pg_url != 'cms'
AND root_pages.pg_content_1 LIKE '%".$this->search."%'
OR root_pages.pg_content_2 LIKE '%".$this->search."%'

AND root_pages.pg_content_1 NOT LIKE '%http://%'
AND root_pages.pg_content_2 NOT LIKE '%http://%'

ORDER BY root_pages.pg_created DESC
";

$items = parent::fetch_all($sql);

return $items;
  }
}
```

then I call the object of search,

```
$output = new search('1');
print_r($output->get_result());
```

but I get lots of errors instead,

> Warning: mysqli::query()
>   [mysqli.query]: Couldn't fetch search
>   in C:\wamp\www\xxx\class_database.php
>   on line xx
>
> Warning: database::get_error()
>   [database.get-error]: Couldn't fetch
>   search in
>   C:\wamp\www\xxx\class_database.php on
>   line xx
>
> Warning: mysqli::close()
>   [mysqli.close]: Couldn't fetch search
>   in C:\wamp\www\xxx\class_database.php
>   on line xx

What have I done incorrectly? How can I fix it?

Thanks.

**EDIT:**

When I tried to call the child class (search) from the parent class (database) in this way,

```
$database = new database(DB_HOST,DB_USER,DB_PASS,DB_NAME);
print_r(search::get_result());
```

then I get this error,

> Fatal error: Non-static method
>   mysqli::query() cannot be called
>   statically in
>   C:\wamp\www\xxx\class_database.php on
>   line

Sigh...

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think extending the class from `database` class is probably a bad idea...

Here is my solution:

```
class search
{

    public $mysqli = null;

    public function __construct($mysqli)
    {
       $this->mysqli = $mysqli;
    }

    public function get_result($parameter)
    {
        $sql = "
        SELECT *
        FROM root_contacts_cfm
        WHERE root_contacts_cfm.cnt_id = '".$parameter."'
        ORDER BY cnt_id DESC
        ";

        $item = $this->mysqli->fetch_assoc($sql);
        return $item;
    }
}
```

Passing the object `database` class into the `search` class instead, so I can call this search class by this:

```
$mysqli = new database(DB_HOST,DB_USER,DB_PASS,DB_NAME);
$output = new search($mysqli);
print_r($output->get_result('1'));
```

Am I right...?

Answer (score 1):

Because the `search` property in the `search` class is non-static, you have to first instantiate an object:

```
$database = new database(DB_HOST,DB_USER,DB_PASS,DB_NAME);
$search = new search("search term");
print_r($search->get_result());
```

Maybe have a read of a basic tutorial on OOP in PHP, the first one from Google:

http://www.killerphp.com/tutorials/object-oriented-php/

EDIT: There's also a few calls to `self::get_error();` in your `database` class, these should be re-written as instance methods rather than class methods:

`$this->get_error()`

Answer (score 1):

You are using the wrong method to call methods of the `mysqli` class in your `database` class.

You only want to use the double colon `::` when accessing static methods, static properties, constants, or the parent of the current method you are overwriting. None of the methods in the mysqli class are static despite how the php manual lists them with the `::` in the list of methods.

The way you use `parent::__construct()` in your `__construct()` is correct because you are in the current method of the parent you are overwriting.

But in your other methods you want to use `$this->` to refer to other parent methods.

In `fetch_all()` and `fetch_assoc()` use `$this->query()` instead of `parent::query()`.

In `__destruct()` use `$this->close();` instead.

When you use `self::get_error();`, you will either want to change that to `$this->` or modify your the function definition to make it static like so `public static function get_error()`

Comment: thanks. I just changed them and tested the class but I get this error this time: `Fatal error: Maximum function nesting level of '100' reached, aborting! in C:\wamp\www\xx\class_database.php on line 385`

Comment: line 385 refers to this code which is in `database` clase: `public function query($query)
 {
  $result = $this->query($query);
  if($result) 
  {
   return $result;
  }
  else
  {
   return $this->get_error();
  }

 }`

Comment: You will want to use `parent::query()` there because you *are in* the function that is overwriting the parent `query()`.